# Merge array of object in js based on spcific values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of object for classes which includes class status and class time. I want to group the classes based on same start and end time so students can see which classes are closed, which ones are open. For the ones which are open, which ones have the same start and end time.

It should group if **all sets of start and end times are the same**. So because Math and Gym have the same start and end time, they are group together. Spanish class has 1 set of start and end time as Math and Gym but shouldnt be grouped because it has additional start and end time.

So group them like this:

```
class_name                              class_status  class_hours
Math - Gym                              Open          [Class Hours]
Science - Art - History - Language      Closed        [No Hours]
Spanish                                 Open          [Class Hours]
Physics                                 Open          [Class Hours]
```

```js
var list = {
  "time_table": [{
    "class_name": "Math",
    "class_status": "open",
    "class_hrs": [{
      "start": "070000",
      "end": "131400"
    }, {
      "start": "131500",
      "end": "132000"
    }]
  }, {
    "class_name": "Science",
    "class_status": "closed",
    "class_hrs": false
  }, {
    "class_name": "Art",
    "class_status": "closed",
    "class_hrs": false
  }, {
    "class_name": "History",
    "class_status": "closed",
    "class_hrs": false
  }, {
    "class_name": "Language",
    "class_status": "closed",
    "class_hrs": false
  }, {
    "class_name": "Gym",
    "class_status": "open",
    "class_hrs": [{
      "start": "070000",
      "end": "131400"
    }, {
      "start": "131500",
      "end": "132000"
    }]
  },{
    "class_name": "Spanish",
    "class_status": "open",
    "class_hrs": [{
      "start": "070000",
      "end": "131400"
    }, {
      "start": "131500",
      "end": "132000"
    },
    {
      "start": "211500",
      "end": "222000"
    }]
  },
  {
    "class_name": "Physics",
    "class_status": "open",
    "class_hrs": [{
      "start": "080000",
      "end": "131400"
    }, {
      "start": "141500",
      "end": "152000"
    }]
  }]
};

function mergeValues(list) {
  let obj = Object.fromEntries(list.map(({
    class_hrs
  }) => [class_hrs, {
    count: 0,
    class_name: [],
  }]));
  list.forEach(({
    class_hrs,
    class_name,
  }) => {
    obj[class_hrs].count++;
    obj[class_hrs].class_name.push(class_name);
  });
  return obj;
}

console.log(mergeValues(list.time_table));
```

can someone help me achieve the desired output?

Comment: Hi @Rain Man
Object key must be string. Not object

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this.

```
function mergeValues(list) {
  let obj = Object.fromEntries(list.map(({
    class_hrs
  }) => [JSON.stringify(class_hrs), {
    count: 0,
    class_name: [],
  }]));
  list.forEach(({
    class_hrs,
    class_name,
  }) => {
    obj[JSON.stringify(class_hrs)].count++;
    obj[JSON.stringify(class_hrs)].class_name.push(class_name);
  });
  return obj;
}
```

If you follow this, you won't lost `class_hrs` information.

Comment: thank you, do you know if it is possible to get an object similar to the output I posted? so dont set hours as keys but just group it based on that

Comment: please explain me detailed info

Comment: well... Nowadays, I am super busy.

Comment: Actually, I am freelancer. if you have any job for me, pls provide me.